# OWASP ZAP docker file with python3 and robot framework

Tags: proxy, dockerfile, robotframework, docker-container, zap

I created a docker file using a base image of `OWASP ZAP stable` and added steps to download python3, robot framework, and all required pip3 packages. Also added step to set proxy and zap port number in the docker file.

Docker build is created successfully, I am able to run docker image. While running my robot zap test suite inside the container I am facing `cannot connect to proxy` error.

> (False, ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost',
> port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url:
> http://zap/JSON/core/action/shutdown/?apikey=4l3lp7s1903u7f06kjfj67pjnk
> (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7fb3d8dc3898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused',)))",),))' != 'True'

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this proxy error coming from a docker container?

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail. What's listening on port 8000? How are you launching ZAP? How are you starting the docker container? Where are you trying to access it from? RoboZap isn't supported by the core team, you should hit up we45 (or whoever) for support.

Comment: @kingthorin Yes using 8000 proxy port. Create dockerfile using bash image as ZAP stable image. Running using: "sudo docker run -p 80:8000 -td zap:1 bash" command.

Comment: @vidhi pandya How did you solve it ? I am getting same error with docker.